# How to use dll in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have develop a C# solution to add some jquery functions. I wonder how can I add the dll solution's to my SharePoint  Project?
What I need to transform the dll to wsp?
or how can I use the dll in the  project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add reference in your SharePoint Project for the dlls created using.

Right Click on Project > Add Reference and give path of your dll.

After adding dlls you will be able to use the methods exposed in the dll.

You can also [package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521697/include-3rd-party-dll-in-the-sharepoint-project-while-packaging-the-wsp) the dll in your wsp. So when your wsp will be deployed, the dll will be deployed with that.

Comment: it's an out of the box,project,whith no coding. I guess i need to create a wsp solution ?

Comment: Of course !! create a wsp USING SharePoint project and add dll

Comment: Look the deploying customisations process in Sharepoint: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc263205(office.14)

Comment: let me know if you face any other problem